# How does the new ranking system work?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike, competitive-gaming

How does the new ranking system work? It has been relased in the winter update.

I want to share a little story:

I was playing matchmaking. At the end of the match it has been 14:16, approx. 30 kills, 7 MVPs, best score of my team. And I got deranked. Also there were 2 trolls in our team.

I also noticed recently that the new ranking system matches me up with players that are **4 ranks below my rank!**. I just don't understand it, as my score was high enough and also we won the previous game. So does it derank me because I lost one match?

Comment: AFAIK, it deranked everyone by one rank after the first match they lost.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What changes were made to the CS:GO ranking system?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/250602/what-changes-were-made-to-the-csgo-ranking-system)

Comment: This should be the primary of the dupe, and the linked question closed to this one.

Comment: @MBraedley the other one has more highly upvoted answers so imo this should be the dupe.

Comment: We do not dupe on quality of answers!  Answers can (and in this case, should) be merged.  We try our best to not dupe to low quality questions, and we try our best to dupe to older questions.  This question is older and better quality.  Its only problem was that it didn't have an upvoted answer, which has now been solved.

Comment: @MBraedley where's it say that? The two meta posts I found on this topic [1](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10796/106901) and [2](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10723/106901) say that the question with better answers should be the original. And the quality of the questions I'd say are exactly the same, they're both very similar. The other one was a lot worse but has since been edited to be a more quality question.

Comment: @Aequitas: Quality of answers is only a factor when age and quality of the questions are not factors.  The linked question is obviously inferior to this one, as is evidenced by the fact that it was closed.  The two linked meta questions provide little support for your position, and provide support for my position that question quality is more important.

Comment: I got 2x derank after 5 matches with like 2 ties 1 loss and 2 wins >.< Goodbye double ak :'(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I know, the ranking system itself is the same as it was before. The reason many people are being deranked is because they have made it much harder to get higher ranks. They have done this so that there is less variety in higher ranks (especially Global Elite and such) as before there was too much variation in skill level and too many players at higher ranks. Valve are making the rank spread into a bell curve with Gold Nova 4 at the centre.

***Statement from Valve:***

> We did initiate a slow shift of the Skill Group boundaries recently, due to an increase in players and a substantial upward drift over time in the skill groups distribution. While this won’t impact the quality of your matches (you are matched based on an underlying rank value and not the visible Skill Group), many players will experience a change in their Skill Group as the distribution returns to a bell curve centered approximately at Gold Nova 4. We also shipped a recent update that will automatically monitor and maintain consistency of the players skill groups distribution. That should eliminate the need to make such disruptive boundary adjustments in the future.